# How can I define a managed storage schema for my Google Chrome App that supports a nested object structure?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I know the [official reference](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/storage) is here.

I am having trouble understanding if I can have a `managed_schema` structured like this?

```
schema = {};
schema.propertyA = {};
schema.propertyA.property1 = "1";
schema.propertyA.property2 = "2";
schema.propertyB = "B";
```

And if so, how would the uploaded policy config file look like?

Comment: The docs say there should be one top level property named `properties` that contains the properties, see an example at the end of that page.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest properties in a `managed_schema` just fine with the "object" type.  For your example, the schema would look like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "propertyA": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "property1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "property2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "propertyB": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

And with this policy schema, the uploaded config file would have this format:

```
{
    "propertyA": {
        "Value": {
            "property1": "1",
            "property2": "2"
        }
    },
    "propertyB": {
        "Value": "B"
    }
}
```

I've found [this page](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-policy-for-extensions) useful when configuring and testing Chrome apps with the managed storage API.

Comment: Does it also help in defining and using custom key value pair such as email id or user id under configuring policy for extensions?